# how to select text between tags without selecting carriage return character(<CR>) in vim?

Tags: vim

```
<div>
<p>hello world</p>
...
</div>
```

I want to select only line 2 till one line before the last line of div tag
I know `vit` can select text between tags.
but it will select line 1's carriage return character as well.
Is there a method can simply do what I want?
(I just want this motion to indent some text.)

Comment: Would this question be more suitable for vi.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(So it turns out my answer was completely wrong.)

`it` covers every character from just after the `>` of the opening tag to just before the `<` of the closing tag. If the opening and closing tags are on different lines, as in your example, the area covered by `it` effectively begins on the line of the opening tag and ends on the line of the closing tag. This is less than ideal because we intuitively think about the inner tag as the *lines* between those two tags, not the *characters* between them.

This is why I added the following snippet to `after/ftplugin/html.vim` many years ago and promptly forgot about it:

```
function! Vit() range
    if line("'<") != line("'>")
        normal! gvojV
    else
        normal! gv
    endif
endfunction
xnoremap it it:<C-u>call Vit()<CR>
onoremap it :<C-u>normal vit<CR>
```

The function is pretty simple: if the selection covers multiple lines, it is reduced by one line at the top and one line at the bottom, if not, it is left as-is.

The visual mode mapping is non-recursive, so it executes the custom function after a regular `vit`.

The operator-pending mode mapping does a recursive `vit`, which means that it uses our custom `it` motion.

Comment: thanks for the comment.
this is the neater answer for a wireless vim man like me...

Comment: I apologize if this is trivial, but `>it` performs the exact same operation as `>at` for me. (?!) Also, `dit` deletes the inner HTML without affecting the tags themselves, but does _not_ spare the newline after the opening tag, so that I end up with `<div></div>`. For comparison, neither `>i}` nor `di}` show this kind of behavior (when applied to, say, C code); they work in a similar way to what you described in the answer. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: [part 1] `>it` and `>at` are not supposed to have the same effect in general but that effect largely depends on where the cursor is when you do those commands, mostly because of the nested nature of XML/HTML. In OP's example and with the cursor on line 1 or line 4, `>it` indents lines 2-3 while `>at` indents lines 1-4.

Comment: Well, maybe my `vimrc` is missing some bug-fixing code (which yours might include), then. `>it` and `>at` produce the same result regardless of cursor position. But this behavior only applies to tag blocks; `>iB` and `>aB` for instance operate as intended. Invoking Vim as `vim -u NONE` or `vim --clean` does not make any difference. Apparently a very similar question seems to have been asked some years ago: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13050/how-can-i-shift-only-inner-contents-of-html-element . The accepted answer was most certainly not `>it`, but some rather involved `vimrc` code.

Comment: @Vicky well if that's not a case of over-confidence I don't know what it is. Indeed I have had a custom pseudo-text-object for a long while in my config that I completely forgot. I'm not sure how I can fix such a wrong answer. I guess I will rewrite it completely and ask OP to re-evaluate it. This is *very* awkward, especially given my general attitude toward Vim customisation. Gaah.

Comment: @JoJoMyHero, please re-evaluate this answer, the previous version was completely wrong.

Comment: @romainl Thank you for all your efforts. It’s my fault for misunderstanding the answer. I just used >it for the inner <p> tag. And i forgot all the other tags between <div>. The answer is re-evaluated.

Comment: Answer confirmed.Thank you
@Vicky Thank you so much.The macro below is also very useful too! 
   vit:^U'<+1,'>>^M

Comment: @romainl I was bewildered, "how can `>it` work just fine for everyone except me??" Lol. I'm glad the issue has been cleared up now. Your solution is very elegant. BTW, this question was about a completely unindented text block. If the line containing the closing `</div>` tag included leading characters, however, I guess we would need to check whether these characters are whitespace only or not, in order to substitute something like `gvkojV` for the `gvojV` when appropriate. Does your `html.vim` also handle such cases?

Comment: @Vicky it doesn't, probably because that snippet has been giving me 100% satisfaction.

Comment: Oh okay... just out of curiosity!